# Trigger Jenkins Job for every parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have created a **Global choice Parameter** using [Extensible Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter) plugin.

I am using this parameter list in one of my parametrized jenkins job.

Is there a way in jenkins, where I can execute the job with each of the parameters in the Global choice Parameter list?

I have had a look on **Build Flow** job in jenkins, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240254/jenkins-builds-loop-list) answer, but it seems it accepts hardcoded parameters only, and not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve this using the following steps (with great help from [this](https://www.tikalk.com/devops/showmethemoney/) post) -

As my parameters list is dynamic in nature, it could be added or modified according to other jobs, we have managed it in a text file.

Next, We have used Extensible Choice Parameter plugin to display the parameters, using the groovy script -

```
def list = [];
File file = new File("D:/JenkinJob/parameterList.txt")

file.eachLine { line ->
  list.add("$line")
}
return list
```

[image]

Now I want to call this jenkins job for each of the parameter.
For this, I have installed, **BuildFlow** plugin, and crated a new jenkins job of BuildFlow type - 
[image]

Next, get the **Extended Choice Parameter** plugin, and configure it as follows - 
[image]

Now in the flow step of this job, write this script, where "Feature" is the parameter, that is just created above, and within call to "build" parameter, pass in the name of job which we want to call for each parameter -

```
def features = params['Features'].split(',')

for (feature in features ) {
    build("JobYouWantToCall", JobParameter: feature,)
}
```